# Publishing a npm package that contains .d.ts files for multiple versions of TypeScript

Tags: typescript

There had been a problem with publishing declaration files for multiple versions of TypeScript under @types organization, which was solved recently.

https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/214

There is another way to publish declaration files to npm, as [described](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html).

> 1. bundling with your npm package

Is there any solution that can be applied to this way?
Or is it being discussed somewhere?

Comment: Created an issue for this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`typesVersions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#version-selection-with-typesversions) has been introduced into TypeScript 3.1 for this purpose.

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "package-name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "types": "./index.d.ts", // .d.ts location for TypeScript versions < 3.1
  "typesVersions": {
    ">=3.1": { "*": ["ts3.1/*"] } // .d.ts location for TypeScript versions >= 3.1
  }
}
```